# How to deal with async "using" statement pitfall?

Tags: c#, async-await, using

It's possible to use the result of async methods in "using" statements, e.g.:

```
using (await fooAsync())
{
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it's easy to make this mistake:

```
using (fooAsync())
{
    ...
}
```

And once you do make this mistake, it can be difficult to detect. If the Task you get back happens to be completed, Task.Dispose will complete successfully. It also turns out that [Task.Dispose does not call Task.Result.Dispose](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,9da675dba0391f21), so the object you actually wanted to protect with the "using" statement is left hanging.

As the author of fooAsync, what is the best way to prevent the mistake from being silently ignored?

Comment: A Roslyn code analyzer could detect this, I think.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Visual Studio gives me a handy green squiggly underline when I forget my `await`s.  The green squiggly is a reminder that something might be wrong, but won't throw an error either at compile or at runtime.

Comment: One easy way to avoid this is to start relying on `IAsyncDisposable` and `await using`, which cannot be confused with `using` block syntax. Obviously this is not something you can decide to do unilaterally as an API author.

Comment: It’s odd to have a Disposable type where you don’t use any of its members in the using block, which is the only time this would happen.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That's a good point. It may very well be that in most cases when you don't need the object in the block, it won't fail silently. In my case it was a wrapper around SemaphoreSlim to make the using-block a critical section. That doesn't exactly fail silently, but it also doesn't provide a good error message.

Comment: @Fax That's valid. Is that from a library? I was just testing this out with the [`Nito.AsyncEx`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) library, and it turns out @StephenCleary created an [`AwaitableDisposable`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/AwaitableDisposable.cs) class to address exactly this (see the comments at the top of that class).

Comment: @GabrielLuci That's a good find, you should make an answer out of that.

Comment: @Fax I added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You'll just have to be careful.

While Visual Studio does normally warn you if you don't await a `Task` in normal code, it does not if it's the subject of a `using`. For example:

[image: Lacking await]

Notice that lack of squiggly on the `using` line.

As you mentioned, [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) does implement `IDisposable`, so that's perfectly valid code, which makes it difficult to say if that's *really* a bug. You could always [log an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) just to start that discussion.

That said, if you look at the code for `Task.Dispose()`, it does [throw an exception](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1859) if it's disposed before it's completed.

```cs
// Task must be completed to dispose
if (!IsCompleted)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString("Task_Dispose_NotCompleted"));
}
```

So, while not guaranteed, there is a good chance you'll get hit with that exception while testing if you forget to await.

This is really only an issue if you don't use the disposable object inside the `using`, which is quite rare. Otherwise, you'll figure it out pretty quick:

```cs
using (var foo = FooAsync()) {
    foo.WhyDoesNothingWork();
}
```

However, as you noted, a very reasonable usage where you wouldn't use the disposable object inside the block is with implementations of asynchronous locks, like [`Nito.AsyncEx`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx):

```cs
using (await _mutex.LockAsync()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

It turns out Stephen Cleary created an [`AwaitableDisposable`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/AwaitableDisposable.cs) class to address exactly this. See the comments at the top of that class:

> An awaitable wrapper around a task whose result is disposable. The wrapper is not disposable, so this prevents usage errors like "using (MyAsync())" when the appropriate usage should be "using (await MyAsync())".

I found another implementation of the same thing here: [The Issue With Scoped Async Synchronization Constructs](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2017/02/21/task-wrapper/)

Comment: The main problem with the IsCompleted check is that the first version of the API might use Task.FromResult, while the next version doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the Roslyn Analyzer approach, the following should be enough to get you started. This will check for any invocations within a using block that do not have an await, determine if they are a generic task, and check if their generic task argument is or implements IDisposable.

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class AsyncUsingAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "UnAwaitedTaskInUsing";

    private const string Title = "Await Async Method";
    private const string MessageFormat = "{0} should be awaited";
    private const string Description = "Detected un-awaited task in using.";
    private const string Category = "Usage";

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SyntaxKind.UsingStatement);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var invocationExpression = context.Node.ChildNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if(invocationExpression == null) return;

        var awaitKeyword = context.Node.ChildTokens().OfType<AwaitExpressionSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if(awaitKeyword != null) return;

        var symbolInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationExpression).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
        if(symbolInfo == null) return;

        var genericType = (symbolInfo.ReturnType as INamedTypeSymbol);
        if (!genericType?.IsGenericType ?? false || genericType.Name.ToString() != "Task'1")
            return;

        var genericTypeParameter = genericType.TypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
        if(genericTypeParameter == null)
            return;

        var disposable = context.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.IDisposable");
        if(!disposable.Equals(genericTypeParameter) && !genericTypeParameter.Interfaces.Any(x => disposable.Equals(x)))
            return;

        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocationExpression.GetLocation(), invocationExpression);
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}
```

Currently, the severity is set to 'Warning', but you can easily make this an error that will throw at compile time should someone forget to await their task.

I wouldn't consider this a complete solution, but it should be enough to get you started on one.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose this has to be added to every codebase that uses FooAsync from an assembly?

Comment: @Fax Yes, it would need to be added as an analyzer to any projects you would want it to be used on. However, it is possible to target analyzers to be built as visual studio extensions. I haven't looked too far into it, but I believe if you do so you would just need to deploy it as an extension to your team's VS installations to get the functionality.